# Play/pause audio button using HTML5 and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad, html

I am trying to incorporate sound effects into a HTML5 based digital comic book which will be published for iPad only.  I want to use a simple play/pause button.  I have been playing around all day but I am still struggling with my limited JavaScript knowledge.  Here's the link to the comic and a functionality spec:

http://spiritdigital.co.uk/outpost/issue-interactive/05.html

I want to:

- Have a clickable area over a particular scene (in this case, the car scene)
- On click, a sound plays and the 'play' icon changes to a pause icon
- On second click (when sound is playing) the sound pauses and icon switches back to play
- If sound ends, icon changes back to play

So far, I have the clickable area and the sound plays when the area is clicked but I need your help for the rest.

Comment: Really nice artwork by the way.

Comment: Thank you, I agree.  The artist is exceptionally talented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeschafe/4rWca/)

Basically there's two events that fire, play and pause, when you do the respective action.  I'm just binding to these to toggle the button image (in this case I just change the background-position as it's an image sheet).

Any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you jeschafe, that was exactly the solution I was looking for.

I have it working now: http://www.spiritdigital.co.uk/outpost/issue-interactive/05.html

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="myaudio">
    <source src="song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Now to play the song :

```
var audio = document.getElementById('myaudio');
audio.play();
```

Pause:

```
audio.pause();
```

To change the background image of your div :

```
var control = document.getElementById('yourdiv');
control.style.backgroundImage = 'pathtoanotherimage';
```